Pusher broadcasting with tenancyforlaravel, user not recognized
I have laravel 11.x and tenancyforlaravel 3.8 with subdomains, I have there to implement broadcasting for private channel but the user is not recognized, I assume the tenant is not detected correctly. I get in console /broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)
Through deep debugging I came to the following path /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster::auth() and $this->retrieveUser($request, $channelName) returns null, in the non tenancy project I got User object.
In: BroadcastServiceProvider I tried to add several middleware options but without success:
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [InitializeTenancyByDomainOrSubdomain::class,PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class]]);

Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth']]);

Of course I checked stackoverflow and other sources but my issue is related only to tenancyforlaravel implementation.
Is anyone aware how to handle authenticated users for private channels with tenancyforlaravel?
